# What is the difference between SIGSTOP and SIGTSTP?

Tags: unix, signals, signal-handling

Just wondering about the difference between `SIGSTOP` and `SIGTSTP` signals.

Answer (score 210):

Both signals are designed to suspend a process which will be eventually resumed with `SIGCONT`. The main differences between them are:

- `SIGSTOP` is a signal sent programmatically (eg: `kill -STOP pid` ) while `SIGTSTP` (for ***sig***nal - **t**erminal **stop**) may also be sent through the `tty` driver by a user typing on a keyboard, usually <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>.
- `SIGSTOP` cannot be ignored. `SIGTSTP` might be.

Comment: Factoid: If you're a linux programmer, SIGTSTP is what you get when you use Ctrl-Z to interrupt a process running in a shell without killing it. This usually causes the shell to put it on a suspended job list.

Comment: @Archer I'm not sure to understand your comment. Do you mean you believe `Control-Z` doesn't trigger `SIGTSTP` or do you think it should not?

Comment: @jlliagre I did a closer survey, and it turned out that you are right. I deleted the previous comment.

Comment: @Archer Ok, my guess is you were confused by the manual page terminology. `terminal stop` means TSTP.

Comment: @jlliagre I want to, but the system won't allow it, it says I can only cancel the downvote if the answer is edited…

Comment: @jlliagre if I understood correctly - `SIGSTOP` can be send only through command `kill -STOP pid` and `SIGTSTP` can be send in 2 ways, through command and by `ctrl` + `z` - Am I correct?

Comment: @ManuelJordan `SIGSTOP` can be sent by most programming languages, not only the shell. For example in python, that would be `os.kill(pid, signal.SIGSTOP)`

Comment: @jlliagre interesting that scenario - huge thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 54):

According with the `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/signum.h` file exists the following:

```
#define SIGSTOP     19  /* Stop, unblockable (POSIX).  */
#define SIGTSTP     20  /* Keyboard stop (POSIX).  */
```

Comment: On Solaris 10, the signals are defined in the header file `/usr/include/sys/iso/signal_iso.h`

Comment: In FreeBSD 11 it's at `/usr/include/sys/signal.h`

Answer (score 3):

SIGSTOP can't be ignored by the targetted process.

A good example of that is the video player `mpv`, it can ignore `SIGTSTP` but not `SIGSTOP`.

You can test with a video running :

`kill -SIGTSTP $(pidof mpv)`
and
`kill -SIGSTOP $(pidof mpv)`

Of course `kill -SIGCONT $(pidof mpv)` to resume playing.

Answer (score 2):

on macOS, execute command `man signal` to read signal documentation.

| # | Name | Default Action | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | SIGSTOP | stop process | stop (cannot be caught or ignored) |
| 18 | SIGTSTP | stop process | stop signal generated from keyboard |

There are two differences between them:

- `SIGTSTP` can be caught or ignored, `SIGSTOP` cannot.
- `SIGTSTP` can be generated from keyboard (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>), `SIGSTOP` cannot.

Answer (score 0):

on ubuntu,  `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/signum-generic.h`

```c
#ifdef __USE_XOPEN
# define SIG_HOLD ((__sighandler_t) 2)  /* Add signal to hold mask.  */
#endif

/* We define here all the signal names listed in POSIX (1003.1-2008);
   as of 1003.1-2013, no additional signals have been added by POSIX.
   We also define here signal names that historically exist in every
   real-world POSIX variant (e.g. SIGWINCH).

   Signals in the 1-15 range are defined with their historical numbers.
   For other signals, we use the BSD numbers.
   There are two unallocated signal numbers in the 1-31 range: 7 and 29.
   Signal number 0 is reserved for use as kill(pid, 0), to test whether
   a process exists without sending it a signal.  */

/* ISO C99 signals.  */
#define SIGINT      2   /* Interactive attention signal.  */
#define SIGILL      4   /* Illegal instruction.  */
#define SIGABRT     6   /* Abnormal termination.  */
#define SIGFPE      8   /* Erroneous arithmetic operation.  */
#define SIGSEGV     11  /* Invalid access to storage.  */
#define SIGTERM     15  /* Termination request.  */

/* Historical signals specified by POSIX. */
#define SIGHUP      1   /* Hangup.  */
#define SIGQUIT     3   /* Quit.  */
#define SIGTRAP     5   /* Trace/breakpoint trap.  */
#define SIGKILL     9   /* Killed.  */
#define SIGBUS      10  /* Bus error.  */
#define SIGSYS      12  /* Bad system call.  */
#define SIGPIPE     13  /* Broken pipe.  */
#define SIGALRM     14  /* Alarm clock.  */

/* New(er) POSIX signals (1003.1-2008, 1003.1-2013).  */
#define SIGURG      16  /* Urgent data is available at a socket.  */
#define SIGSTOP     17  /* Stop, unblockable.  */
#define SIGTSTP     18  /* Keyboard stop.  */
#define SIGCONT     19  /* Continue.  */
#define SIGCHLD     20  /* Child terminated or stopped.  */
#define SIGTTIN     21  /* Background read from control terminal.  */
#define SIGTTOU     22  /* Background write to control terminal.  */
#define SIGPOLL     23  /* Pollable event occurred (System V).  */
#define SIGXCPU     24  /* CPU time limit exceeded.  */
#define SIGXFSZ     25  /* File size limit exceeded.  */
#define SIGVTALRM   26  /* Virtual timer expired.  */
#define SIGPROF     27  /* Profiling timer expired.  */
#define SIGUSR1     30  /* User-defined signal 1.  */
#define SIGUSR2     31  /* User-defined signal 2.  */
```