# Signals for pause/unpause a process

Tags: c, operating-system

Is there a  signal what can be given from a father process to pause a child process?If so,what is the signal to unpause again?

Comment: Not in standard C, no. Please edit your question and specify the system used, otherwise this can't be answered.

Answer (score 0):

SIGSTOP and SIGCONT. Man page on signal can explain more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SIGSTOP and SIGCONT:

- SIGSTOP is a signal sent programmatically (eg: kill -STOP pid ) while
  SIGTSTP (for signal - terminal stop) may also be sent through the tty
  driver by a user typing on a keyboard, usually Control-Z.
- SIGSTOP cannot be ignored. SIGTSTP might be.

Remember that both signals are designed to suspend a process which will be eventually be resumed with SIGCONT

You can also check the [official manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for further info!

I advise you to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11886812/whats-the-difference-between-sigstop-and-sigtstp), as it is a similar question to yours, and there are a lot of resources there!