# Suspending a process using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hi i'm new to programming and learning. I have started a project that will automatically make everyone in your grand theft auto 5 session leave. You can achieve this manually by suspending the GTA5 process for around 7 seconds and resuming, but, I can't seem to find out how to suspend a process with code. I have tried importing System.Diagnostics and other imports but cant seem to find any method of doing so, any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code you already have?

Comment: Please take time to take the [tour] and read [ask] and to work following the [mcve]

Comment: Not possibe using regular .NET code. Possible duplicate of [How to suspend/resume a process in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010165/how-to-suspend-resume-a-process-in-windows)

Comment: put the process to sleep