# How to prevent a service executable from being suspended? (C++, win32)

Tags: c++, winapi, process, windows-services, setwindowshookex

I created a windows service which does not accept PAUSE nor STOP. Thus my service itself does not react on STOP or PAUSE SERVICE CONTROLS.
However the service executable can be suspended from taskmanager or resource monitor.
How to avoid that too?

I tried manipulate the ServiceCtrlHandler method of CServiceBase, on SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE call it should just ignore it. But it does not work.
I found out that the suspend in resource monitor calls NtSuspendProcess routine but I am just not sure if I should hook that function to be able to meet my requirements or is ther another way?
I also tried to write a driver using ObRegisterCallbacks to protect the process but it seems to not do anything. (I took the code from windows-driver-samples code)

Comment: What do you mean by "suspend" ? That's not an official Win32 operation on processes. No such thing as  `SIGSTOP/SIGCONT`, that's UNIX. There's [`NtSuspendProcess`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010165/how-to-suspend-resume-a-process-in-windows) but that's not from Task Manager.

Comment: Actuallly it is from the Resource Monitor, when I click on Suspend process there the NtSuspendProcess is called.

Comment: Given that `NtSuspendProcess` is (currently) equivalent to calling `NtSuspendThread`  on every thread of your process, you'd need at least two hooks in general. And debuggers use yet another technique.